# [domain]/? redirect to [domain] using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We are receiving traffic from an important source but they are sending them to our domain with a /? at the end of it. I have tried to redirect with an entry in our .htaccess but this doesn't work:

```
Redirect /? http://[domain]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

I also tried backslashing it:

```
Redirect /\? http://[domain]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

Anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `Redirect` directive as more advanced `mod_rewrite` is needed for this case.

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]*)\?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]
```